# Custom CSS edit

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new in building sites and I don't understand a lot of coding but I need to ask this question ( I guess it's simple but for me it's not). I have products on my homepage and they have borders. I need to remove the borders when I click inspect and remove the tick on "border-style: solid;" it's okay. I tried a lot of different codes in Custom CSS but none of them worked. I guess I cannot take the right class. Some examples:

```
.elementor-52 .elementor-element.elementor-element-c51ed78 .eael-product-grid .woocommerce {
    border-style: none;
}
```

or

```
.product .type-product .post-30 .status-publish .first .instock .product_cat-packages 
.product_cat-test .has-post-thumbnail .shipping-taxable .purchasable .product-type-simple {
    border-style: none;
}
```

[image]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: No one knows how your code looks like. What `HTML` have you defined? Which classes go to which elements? 
As-is nobody will be able to answer your question so please add more input.

Comment: Neither of your attempts match the selector in your screen shot. Just copy that list of classes.

Comment: flagged for no minimum reproducible example, we need to see your code to be able to assess how to fix this. please show at least HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border is on your list-element with the class `product`

To get rid of the border you can use this:

```
li.product{
 border-style: none !important;
}
```

You could also use `border: none;`or `border-width: 0;`

The "!important" overwrites any styles even if they are nested more.

It should be looking like this:

[image]

If the li.product-style is not there you made something wrong in your css-file or: the old css-style is still in your cache. In Chrome you can reset the cache and reload by pressing ctrl + F5

Comment: I have tried this now but it's not working. I still have borders.

Comment: You need to find out on which elements the borders are. Then you can overwrite it. The class seems correct for the element on the screenshot you provided. Try checking the list-element with the class product. The style should now be there. If its not there you could try a cache reset.

Comment: .elementor-52 .elementor-element.elementor-element-c51ed78 .eael-product-grid .woocommerce ul.products li.product {
 border-style: none !important;
}

You mean like this ? This also is not working :(

Comment: It is working, thank you ! I try in FireFox and it was working, but still with ctrl + f5 I can't see it in chrome. Thanks for your time !!!